# Why I get error missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle

I try to understand logic and this kind of error but unfortunettly I can not.
I have following query

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT u.*, ur.Roles, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) 
 FROM users u 
 INNER JOIN user_roles ur 
 ON u.User_roleID = ur.id
 ORDER BY u.UserID) AS numberOfRows 
 FROM users u 
 INNER JOIN user_roles ur 
 ON u.User_roleID = ur.id 
 ORDER BY u.UserID) 
 WHERE rownum <= 10
```

The problem here is that when I run I get error

```
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 7 Column: 2
```

Somehow I try a couple of solution and try to understand what the error is, but I can not.
Currently in my user table the situation is following.

```
ACCOUNTNUMBER   VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
ACTIVE_N_TOKEN  NUMBER(10,0)
BANKNUMBER  VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
BIC VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
CITY    VARCHAR2(45 CHAR)
EDITMODE    NUMBER(10,0)
EMAIL   VARCHAR2(45 CHAR)
EMPLOYEENUMBER  VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
FAMILYMEMBERNAME1   VARCHAR2(45 CHAR)
FAMILYMEMBERNAME2   VARCHAR2(45 CHAR)
FAMILYMEMBERNOTE1   VARCHAR2(45 CHAR)
FAMILYMEMBERNOTE2   VARCHAR2(45 CHAR)
FAMILYMEMBERPHONE1  VARCHAR2(45 CHAR)
FAMILYMEMBERPHONE2  VARCHAR2(45 CHAR)
HOURLYRATE  FLOAT
IBAN    VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
LANGUAGE    VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
LASTNAME    VARCHAR2(45 CHAR)
LASTUPDATED DATE
MOBILE  VARCHAR2(45 CHAR)
PARENT_EMAIL    VARCHAR2(45 CHAR)
PASSWORD    VARCHAR2(100 CHAR)
PERSONALNUMBER  VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
PHONE   VARCHAR2(45 CHAR)
POSTALADDRESS1  VARCHAR2(45 CHAR)
POSTALADDRESS2  VARCHAR2(45 CHAR)
PROFESSIONSID   NUMBER(10,0)
PROFILE_IMAGE   VARCHAR2(50 CHAR)
PROJECTPLANSORTINDEX    NUMBER(10,0)
STARTEDITDATE   DATE
STATUS  VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
SURNAME VARCHAR2(45 CHAR)
TYPE    VARCHAR2(45 CHAR)
USER_ROLEID NUMBER(10,0)
USERID  NUMBER(10,0)
ZIPCODE VARCHAR2(45 CHAR)
```

and User_roles table

```
ID  NUMBER(10,0)
ROLES   VARCHAR2(45 CHAR)
```

Currently I expect something like this in output

```
UserID  Parent_email    Password                                   Surname      Lastname            Email            Phone
1       Administrator   1ca112693c2b25f2ab5669dfb3d89e9237b48fb9    Michel       Mikhelson         user@email.com   324242442341


lastUpdated         User_roleID ProfessionsID   Type    PersonalNumber  Mobile  Status  City
2020-04-24 10:10:07  1              1           Hired    1               665652 Active  1

ZipCode PostalAddress1  PostalAddress2  FamilyMemberName1   FamilyMemberPhone1  FamilyMemberNote1   FamilyMemberName2   FamilyMemberPhone2  FamilyMemberNote2   EmployeeNumber
1           1               1               1                   1                   1                       1               1                       1                   1
```

What is wrong here ? Where did I made mistake ?

Comment: No, I have 2 left and 2 right parathesis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `ORDER BY` clause, here:

```
ON u.User_roleID = ur.id 
 ORDER BY u.UserID)             --> here
 WHERE rownum <= 10
```

Why? Because:

```
SQL> select (select count(*) from emp order by 1) from dual;
select (select count(*) from emp order by 1) from dual
                                 *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis


SQL> select (select count(*) from emp) from dual;

(SELECTCOUNT(*)FROMEMP)
-----------------------
                     14

SQL>
```

Comment: Correct, except it's the other ORDER BY that should be removed:
ORDER BY u.UserID) AS numberOfRows  --> here

Answer (score 0):

This is strange.
I don't know what causes the error, but if you leave out the (useless) inner ORDER BY clause, the query works.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make your query much simpler:

```
SELECT u.*, ur.Roles, COUNT(*) OVER () AS numberOfRows 
FROM USERS u 
    INNER JOIN user_roles ur ON u.User_roleID = ur.id 
FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

should return the same result.